# Should I use SHA-1 or SHA-2 with Heroku SSL Endpoint?

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

My DNS has an option to use SHA-1 or SHA-2 for the ssl certificate. Which one should I choose to be compatible with Heroku SSL Endpoint? Does either work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Either should be fine. SHA-2 will break IE6, and all versions of IE on Windows 
XP prior to SP 3. If you're fine with that, go for it.

-Tom Maher
Heroku Security Team
```

Comment: Note that SHA-1 is deprecated, and Google's going to start showing warnings in Chrome for sites using SHA-1 soon: http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html More details here: https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1